# Read and write an NSDecimalNumber

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdecimalnumber

I have a problem with reading and writing NSDecimalNumbers. Say I have this decimal number:

```
NSDecimalNumber *myNumber; // this is 123,23
```

Then I read its value like this and show it in a textField

```
self.textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", myNumber];
```

It'll look like this in a textField: "123.23", notice the dot instead of a comma. If I try to read it into the property again like so, the decimals are excluded. 123 is the only thing that gets read:

```
myNumber = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:self.textField.text];
```

But if I write 123,23 with the keyboard using UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad and a **comma**, it works just fine. Why is this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formatting decimal numbers is a problem. Usually, instead of just using `%@` with `myNumber`, which uses `[NSDecimalNumber description]`, you have to use `[NSDecimalNumber descriptionWithLocale:]`. That will localize the decimal separator.

```
self.textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [myNumber descriptionWithLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
```

If you need other formatting, for example limiting the number of decimal digits or adding grouping separators, you can use `NSNumberFormatter`, however `NSNumberFormatter` converts all numbers to `double` first, so you will always lose precision.

The more robust solution when formatting `NSDecimalNumber` is rolling your own formatter.

Answer (score 0):

```
self.textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,", myNumber];
```

Comment: you miss comma after %@

Answer (score 0):

Please check with below code -

```
self.textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[NSNumberFormatter localizedStringFromNumber:number numberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle]];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDecimalNumber *price = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"120000"];
NSLocale *priceLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en-in"]; 

NSNumberFormatter *currencyFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[currencyFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
[currencyFormatter setLocale:priceLocale];
NSString *format = [currencyFormatter positiveFormat];
[currencyFormatter setPositiveFormat:format];

NSString *currencyString1 = [currencyFormatter stringFromNumber:price];
DLog(@"%@",currencyString1);
```